# G-Suite-like but in another platform like Microsoft?

Tags: saas

When I buy a domain using Google Domains, I got an offer to get G-Suite (now called Google Workspace) to manage email and other stuff (30GB google drive, company policy for accounts, googledocs-youtube integration, some other things I'll never use) related to business/company within that domain. It costs about 4.2$ to 6$ (I think because I paid monthly instead of yearly). Does any other company have similar offer? What does this kind of thing called?

Comment: I believe that Microsoft 365 is a similar offering to G-Suite, but I don't believe that MS offers domain sales (though I believe they'll sell you server space to host your domain).

Comment: What software are you asking about here? What features should it have, what OS should it run on, what is your price limit when it comes to paid software? ;)

Comment: that's the question.. what does g-suite/google workspace software category called?